# Segmentation fault when using scanf or fgets in C language

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I have a project in one of my programming classes to create a 20-questions game that recursively builds up making a binary tree of choices the computer follows as you respond to the questions. The Node files I have made and it has been tested and is working fine. However, I can post it if needed, but I believe my problem is somewhere in my main files.

Failing run of program:

```
Is it a dog?

Enter "y" for yes and "n" for no: n

YOU WIN!!!

What were you thinking of? fish

Please give me a yes or no questions to distinguish dog from fish: does it have scales?

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The program runs absolutely fine and performs as expected until the user enters the distinguishing questions.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Node.h"
#define BUFF 1

//prototype methods
void startGame();
void askQuestion(Node* currentNode);

//Declare variables
Node* startNode;
Node* moveNode;
Node* makeNode;
char ans;
char newQuestion[1000];
char playerObj[1000];

void startGame() {
    //Allocate memory for altering decision tree when new questions are added
    startNode = (Node*) malloc(BUFF * sizeof(Node));
    moveNode = (Node*) malloc(BUFF * sizeof(Node));
    makeNode = (Node*) malloc(BUFF * sizeof(Node));

    //Make root node of tree
    setQuestion("Is it a dog?", startNode);
    setObjName("dog", startNode);

}

void askQuestion(Node* currentNode) {

    printf("%s\n", getQuestion(currentNode));//Ask user a question
    printf("Enter \"y\" for yes and \"n\" for no: ");//Prompt user for response
    scanf("%c", &ans);//Get user character from keyboard
    fflush(stdin);//Flush standard input to clear newline character

    //If the computer is right computer wins
    if((isObjNode(currentNode)) & (ans == 'y')){
        printf("COMPUTER WINS!!!");
        //this section will later start another game using the current decision tree

    //Move to next yes node in tree
    }else if(!(isObjNode(currentNode)) & (ans == 'y')){
        askQuestion(currentNode->yesPointer);

    //If at leaf node and computer is wrong notify user and expand tree
    }else if((isObjNode(currentNode)) & (ans == 'n')){
        printf("YOU WIN!!!\n");

        printf("What were you thinking of? ");
        scanf("%s", &playerObj);//Get what user was thinking of
        fflush(stdin);//Flush newline character

        printf("Please give me a yes or no questions to distinguish %s from             %s: ",currentNode->objName, playerObj);
        fflush(stdout);

        scanf("%s", &newQuestion);
        //I also tried:
        //fgets(newQuestion, sizeof(newQuestion), stdin);
        fflush(stdin);

        //PROGRAM SEGMENTATION FAULTS

        setQuestion(strcat(strcat("Is it a ", playerObj), "?"), makeNode);
        setObjName(playerObj, makeNode);

        moveNode = currentNode;

        printf("If the answer would be %s, what would the answer be y for    yes, n for no?",playerObj);
        scanf("%c", &ans);
        fflush(stdin);
        setQuestion(newQuestion, currentNode);

        if(ans == 'y'){
            setYesNodeRef(currentNode, makeNode);
            setNoNodeRef(currentNode, moveNode);
        }else if(ans == 'n'){
            setYesNodeRef(currentNode, moveNode);
            setNoNodeRef(currentNode, makeNode);
        }

    }else if(!(isObjNode(currentNode)) & (ans == 'n')){
        askQuestion(currentNode->noPointer);
    }

}

int main() {

    startGame();
    askQuestion(startNode);

}
```

So, in short, my question is what is causing the segmentation fault?

I have looked at several post regrading scanf and I have tried fgets as well based on some post and tutorials. fgets wont even let me enter user input when the code is the exact same just changing the scanf to fgets for newQuestion input if it is of any interest.

Thanks everyone in advance for any input or referrals to any information on similar issues.

Comment: The behavior of `fflush(stdin);` is undefined, and it doesn't do what you think anyway. ALSO: provide a compilable example. And do not cast `malloc()`.

Comment: To begin with: 1. `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior. Do not use it. 2. `scanf("%s", &playerObj);` is bad due to type mismatch and risk of buffer overrun. Use `scanf("%999s", playerObj);`. `scanf("%s", &newQuestion);` should also be `scanf("%999s", newQuestion);`.

Comment: `strcat(strcat("Is it a ", playerObj), "?")` is very bad. You mustn't modify string literals, and even if it were allowed to be modified, this code do cause buffer overrun. Allocate enough buffer and use `sprintf()`.

Comment: Take a look at this on strcat: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm

Comment: Maybe you should use `&&` (logical AND) instead of `&` (bitwise AND) in this case.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. I have posted an answer with regards to the specific issues I was having. But I do appreciate the feedback and will use it to adjust my style with C programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again everyone.

The line that reads:
    `strcat(strcat("Is it a ", playerObj), "?")`

Was causing the issue I was experiencing. When I completely commented out the line the program was able to proceed to further points in the program. And I am looking into better ways to do this as user MikeCAT mentions.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you for the tip-off to this. And I will explore sprintf